# Can't use GitHub for 3rd party authentication in Parse Server

Tags: oauth, parse-server

I am trying to setup a simple example of 3rd party authentication in a localhost parse server using GitHub. I read the parse guide, the wiki, as well as old issues and websites (pre- and post- the opensourcing of parse). Almost everything is working, but the last part: the link between the GitHub access token and the Parse.User.

Here's my client and server code.

Client code (using hello.js for connecting with github and getting the access_token):

```
<html>
<body>
<script src="src/hello.polyfill.js"></script>
<script src="src/hello.js"></script>
<script src="src/modules/github.js"></script>
<script src="https://npmcdn.com/parse/dist/parse.min.js"></script>

<button onclick="hello('github').login()">Login with GitHub</button>
<div id='profile'></div>

<script>
const parseClientID = "[MY_PARSE_APP_ID]";
const githubClientID = "[MY_GITHUB_APP_ID]";
Parse.initialize(parseClientID);
Parse.setURL = "http://localhost:1337/parse";
var provider = {
  authenticate(options) {if (options.success) {options.success(this, {});}},
  restoreAuthentication(authData) {},
  getAuthType() {return 'github';},
  deauthenticate() {}
};
let authData = {authData: {access_token: 'REPLACED_ON_THE_FLY', id: githubClientID}};
hello.init({github: githubClientID}, {
    oauth_proxy: 'http://localhost:3000/proxy',
    redirect_uri: 'http://localhost:3000/redirect'
});
// after loging in, when github calls back, this part of the code tries to
// link the github data with a Parse.User
hello.on('auth.login', (auth) => {
    authData.authData.access_token = auth.authResponse.access_token;
    var user = new Parse.User();
    user._linkWith(provider, authData).then(usr=>console.log(usr), err=>console.log(err));
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Server code (nothing fancy, standard parse-server route, and oauthshim to talk with hello.js):

```
var createError = require('http-errors');
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var ParseServer = require('parse-server').ParseServer;
var oauthshim = require('oauth-shim');
var app = express();
app.get('/', (req, res) => {res.render('index');});
app.get('/redirect', (req, res) => {res.render('redirect');});
var api = new ParseServer({
    "appId": "[MY_PARSE_APP_ID]",
    "masterKey": "[MY_PARSE_MASTER_KEY]",
    "appName": "connect",
    "databaseURI": "mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/parse",
    "serverURL": "http://localhost:1337/parse",
    "auth": {"github": {"id":"[MY_GITHUB_APP_ID]","access_token":"spaceholder"}}
});
app.use('/parse', api);
oauthshim.init([{
    client_id: '[MY_GITHUB_APP_ID]',
    client_secret: '[MY_GITHUB_SECRET]',
    grant_url: 'https://github.com/login/oauth/access_token',
    domain: 'http://localhost:3000/redirect'
}]);
app.use('/proxy', oauthshim);
app.listen(1337, function() {console.log('parse-server running on port 1337.');});
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
app.use(function(req, res, next) { next(createError(404));});
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  res.locals.message = err.message;
  res.locals.error = req.app.get('env') === 'development' ? err : {};
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render('error');
});
module.exports = app;
```

The client displays a single "login" button. On clicking, it connects to github, gets an access token, which is then used to user._linkWith().

At this point, I get this error in the Web console:

```
error: Github auth is invalid for this user. code=101, message=Github auth is invalid for this user.
```

I think that I'm not writing the auth object properly, but I can't figure out how to do it just from the Custom Authentication section of the Guide in the parse-server website (https://docs.parseplatform.org/parse-server/guide/#oauth-and-3rd-party-authentication).

Thank you in advance !

Comment: I may have made some progress. The line in the client:
    `Parse.User.logInWith(provider, authData).then(usr=>console.log(usr), err=>console.log(err));`
should be:
    `user.logInWith(provider, authData).then(usr=>console.log(usr), err=>console.log(err));`

Now I get the following error in the server log: `error: Github auth is invalid for this user. code=101, message=Github auth is invalid for this user.`

Comment: I'll modify the code in the question...

Answer (score 0):

I have implemented the github login but not in the same way you did but I think it should work the process should be the same.

You need to get the access token and next with the token get the github user id at https://api.github.com/user. And finaly call the _linkWith method.

On the server side you don't need to add auth configuration. your server should be :

```
var api = new ParseServer({
    "appId": "[MY_PARSE_APP_ID]",
    "masterKey": "[MY_PARSE_MASTER_KEY]",
    "appName": "connect",
    "databaseURI": "mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/parse",
    "serverURL": "http://localhost:1337/parse",
});
```

And on client client side you don't need to configure the provider. Just call _linkWith like that :

```
hello.on('auth.login', (auth) => {
    // get the github user id before
    const authData = {
      id: 'your github user id'
      access_token: 'your access token'
    }
    const user = new Parse.User()
    return user._linkWith('github', { authData }).then(user => {
      // do what you want with user
    })
```

Hope this will help you.